# Setting private field in abstract super class using mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I am having a abstract super class TP and which have a concrete sub class ETP. This is my code:

```
    abstract class TP {

    private Configuration app;        
         protected MC bMC() {    
         }
    }
```

and sub class ETP code is:

```
 public class ETP extends TP {        
    private Configuration app;       
       public MC pT() {
          bMC();
       }
   }
```

I am writing test case for ETP which is ETPTest which looks like this

```
public class ETPTest {       
 @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
       // as TP is abstract i am initializing with ETP
          TP = new ETP();        
       // some initialization
   }    
    Whitebox.setInternalState(TP, app);
}
```

but app is getting passed as null in TP and getting NPE in TP.

any ideas or suggestions?

app is a private variable defined in both TP and ETP; and I am trying to set internal state for app which is in TP.

Comment: Where is app defined? What private member are you talking about?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: None of this is real code, so it's impossible to figure out what might be the cause. Please construct a [minimal test case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Just in case: is there anything I could do to make this upvote-worthy in your eyes as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your difficulties to such things can be seen as a symptom.

You can decide that the cure is to spent hours until you get the *mocking* parts to circumvent around that problem.

Whereas the other option is: **understand** that the given design is **deficient**:

- sub classes should absolutely **not** care about *private* fields in super classes. The whole point of *private* is to make things an "implementation detail" that no other class should know or care about
- Worse: by putting up a **second** private field with the same name, you just added to that confusion. Those will be to different private fields; there is no "overriding" or "polymorphism" here.

In the end, you probably do not understand how to *properly* design a solution that uses inheritance and abstract base classes. You should thus step back, and think for example, if a solution like this helps:

```
public abstract class Base {
  protected abstract Configuration getConfiguration();

  public final void doSomething() {
    ... calls getConfiguration() to do its jobs
  }
}
```

and then:

```
public abstract class Subclass extends Base {
  protected Configuration getConfiguration() {
    return whatever
```

As a rule of thumb: clean, straight-forward, non-surprising designs can most often be unit tested simply by using dependency injection and one mock here and another one there. As soon as you have to look into all these complex "solutions"; such as mocking super-class methods/fields; or mocking static methods, ... you are already suffering from a bad design; and instead of fixing that problem; you try to work around it.

That will not help you in the long run. Because the real problem is the "smelly" design in your production code.

Comment: Yeah but what about a case where one has to unit-test and is not allowed to change the code?

Comment: Then sure, power mock or JMockit might be a helpful tool. But then: what is the point of testing code that you aren't supposed to change? What will you do upon finding a bug? Just leave it in, because you are not supposed to make changes?!

Comment: Welcome to the corporate world my friend... code coverage requirements and no code changes allowed for the moment, but you can raise some bugs for later to be corrected in next deliveries... It's stupid but not my decision.